# Processing Array of Unknown Size in VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

I am working on an assignment where records are read from a file, stored in a structure array, and then output to a listbox.  Per the assignment instructions, the structure array is designated to have a size of 250 elements.

To keep track of the number of records processed, I created the variable named totalElements.  It counts the number of records processed so I have the high number for my For loop that writes to the listbox.  Is this the best way to do this?

In my testing, I found if I processed less than 250 records and elements of the structure array were empty, I would get run time errors when writing the records to the listbox if I used either of these loops.

```
     For i As Integer = 0 To 249          
     ...write listbox       
     Next
```

or

```
     Dim highestSub As Integer = mem.Length - 1 
     For i As Integer = 0 To highestSub 
     ...write listbox 
      Next
```

Here is my complete code.  It works, I just feel like there has to be a better way of doing this.  Thanks in advance for the help!

-Brent

```
    Public Class MainForm

Structure Members
    Public id As String
    Public lastName As String
    Public firstName As String
    Public middleInitial As String
    Public grade As String
    Public classPeriod As String
End Structure

'declare an array of Members
Private mem(250) As Members

Dim totalElements As Integer = 0



Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    LoadStudentFile()

    WriteStudentFile()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub LoadStudentFile()

    Dim inFile As IO.StreamReader
    inFile = IO.File.OpenText("StudentList.txt")
    Dim tempArray(5) As String
    Dim subscript As Integer = 0


    Do Until inFile.Peek = -1

        tempArray = inFile.ReadLine.Split(","c)

        mem(subscript).id = tempArray(0)


        mem(subscript).lastName = tempArray(1)

        mem(subscript).firstName = tempArray(2)

        mem(subscript).middleInitial = tempArray(3)

        mem(subscript).grade = tempArray(4)

        mem(subscript).classPeriod = tempArray(5)

        subscript = subscript + 1

        totalElements = totalElements + 1

    Loop

    inFile.Close()

End Sub


Private Sub WriteStudentFile()


    For i As Integer = 0 To totalElements - 1
        StudentsList.Items.Add(mem(i).id.PadLeft(10, "0") & " " & mem(i).lastName & ", " & mem(i).firstName & " " & mem(i).middleInitial)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for null records before you write your records to the listbox. This is assuming that an ID will be present for all records.

```
Private Sub WriteStudentFile()
    For i As Integer = 0 To mem.Length -1
        If Not IsNothing(mem(i).id) then
            StudentsList.Items.Add(mem(i).id.PadLeft(10, "0") & " " & mem(i).lastName & ", " & mem(i).firstName & " " & mem(i).middleInitial)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Though if you have a choice whether or not to use a array I would use a generic [`List(Of Members)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. That way you could just add the valid data and not have the excess allocation.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that worked very well and was exactly what I was looking for.